# Need help for canvas onload images

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to add a image on my canvas but the error :
Uncaught ReferenceError: context is not defined at Image.maru1 (js.js:36) happened.

I could not find out the reason although I have tried to use many methods to add the image. It would be my pleasure if I could have your help.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function base(){
ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
ctx.fillRect(5, 5, 150, 150);

ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
ctx.fillRect(170, 5, 150, 150);

ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
ctx.fillRect(335, 5, 150, 150);

ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
ctx.fillRect(5, 170, 150, 150);

ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
ctx.fillRect(170, 170, 150, 150);

ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
ctx.fillRect(335, 170, 150, 150);

ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
ctx.fillRect(5, 335, 150, 150);

ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
ctx.fillRect(170, 335, 150, 150);

ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
ctx.fillRect(335, 335, 150, 150);
}

var img = new Image();
img.src = "maru.png";
img.onload = function maru1(){
context.drawImage(this, 180, 180, 140, 140);
}


 //canvas.addEventListener('click', base);
```

Comment: ctx.drawImage(this, 180, 180, 140, 140)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.I have tried to change the code but the error still happen. ctx is still undefined .

Comment: The problem is solved. Thank you very much for your help!